# Can i take half input from file and rest from terminal

Tags: bash, user-input, file-io

i have an executable(grammer) which when runs takes input(facts) from terminal and to end i press Ctrl+D (EOF). After which programs starts taking another input(queries) again to end i press Ctrl+D. 
So what i want to do is input facts from file and queries from terminal.
I've tried

```
./grammer < facts.pl #this assumes that all the input is from file so program terminates after inputting only facts
cat facts.pl queries.pl | ./grammer #this merges both file and removes the EOF in between files
```

Can i input multiple files sequentially i.e. on ending first it executes eof and then start taking input from file2?

Can i somehow input EOF before actually end of file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cat` is short for `concatenate`, so of course the distinction between the two input files is lost. If `./grammer` cannot read files directory by passing the file names as arguments

```
./grammer facts.pl queries.pl
```

you'll need to invoke `./grammer` separately for each file.

```
for f in facts.pl queries.pl; do
    ./grammer < "$f"
done
```